# Cancel some keyboard events on a control

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, event-handling

I have a DataGridView with KeyDown and KeyUp handlers. Under some conditions I want to disable the default behavior of the Enter key down (unselecting text and focusing on the next row), pretty much like this:

```
    private void View_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && Condition)
        {
            // Special flow - do logic and CANCEL default event effect
            SpecialFlow = true;
            ...
            e.Handled = true; // That doesn't do the job
        }
    }

    private void View_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && Condition && SpecialFlow)
        {
            // Special flow - do logic and continue normally
            SpecialFlow = false;
            ...
        }
    }
```

I've found some solutions that don't seem to match my needs:

- Intercept ALL keyboard events in the application with a hook - I need much more checks to do that way.
- Remove ALL event handlers - but I need them back once key is up.
- Implement a new controll - overkill.

So simply put, is there a way to intercept the key event AFTER the handler (right before the default handling) and only if in the special flow?

**Solved:**

The problem I had is that KeyDown was not called at all, because the cell was in edit mode, and there's basically no way to prevent the default behavior of ending edit mode by Enter. So I added a flag for returning to the selected text in edit mode after edit mode was ended - in KeyUp handler.

Pretty much like this:

```
    private void View_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Condition)
            EndEditFlag = true;
    }

    private void View_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && Condition)
        {
            if (EndEditFlag)
            {
                EndEditFlag = false;
                // Select by previously saved selection data - revert CellEndEdit
                View.CurrentCell = View.Rows[...].Cells[...];
                SelectText(...);
            }
            // Special flow - do logic
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. But if I am not wrong all you need is just "Handled" property on the KeyEventArgs object.

When in your event handler you set that property to "true" no further processing for that particular event will be called:

```
    public void Test()
    {
        DataGridView view = new DataGridView();

        view.KeyDown += view_KeyDown;
    }

    void view_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter /* && some other conditions */)
        {
            //Do some custom logic
            e.Handled = true; //Cencel event. Avoid any other processing. Like the button was never pressed.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thnx, but I forgot to mention I tried that, for some reason it didn't work.

Comment: It should do the trick. I guess you are making some mistake in other parts. If you make your own implementation for "Enter" buton and you set the event to handled it will not be forwarded to any other controls. Please make sure with debugger if your call to e.Handled=true is invoked.

Comment: You're right, my problem is getting to the handler from an edited cell.

Answer (score 0):

An in-depth solution to this can get fairly complex. I would recommend to first have a try with the `KeyEventArgs`'s `SuppressKeyPress` property. If you set it to *true* in `View_KeyDown`, the standard behaviour might not get triggered. If so, leave here.

If not, you will have to mess with the way the windows messages are processed on keystrokes. I am doing exactly this, in a project I am working on.

Short outline of my approach:
Put your control(s) in question into a **container** descending from `UserControl`. This allows for overriding the `ProcessKeyPreview` method by some custom code in which the afforementioned messing with the windows messages is done. Essentially, PeekMessage from user32.dll is used to get the unwanted windows messages out of the message queue, after they have been processed by overridden `ProcessKeyPreview`.

So let's dive into the container's code:

```
public class baseKeyControl : UserControl
{
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    private const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
    const int WM_CHAR = 0x102;
    const int WM_SYSCHAR = 0x106;
    const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;
    const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x105;
    const int WM_IME_CHAR = 0x286;

    private struct MSG
    {
        public IntPtr hwnd;
        public int message;
        public IntPtr wParam;
        public IntPtr lParam;
        public int time;
        public int pt_x;
        public int pt_y;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool PeekMessage([In, Out] ref MSG msg,
                                               HandleRef hwnd, int msgMin, int msgMax, int remove);        

    /// <summary>
    /// Trap any keypress before child controls get hold of them
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="m">Windows message</param>
    /// <returns>True if the keypress is handled</returns>
    protected override bool ProcessKeyPreview(ref Message m)
    {
        KeyEventArgs e = null;

        if ((m.Msg != WM_CHAR) && (m.Msg != WM_SYSCHAR) && (m.Msg != WM_IME_CHAR))
        {
            e = new KeyEventArgs(((Keys)((int)((long)m.WParam))) | ModifierKeys);
            if ((m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN) || (m.Msg == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
            {
                this.DoTrappedKeyDown(e);
            }
            else if ((m.Msg == WM_KEYUP) || (m.Msg == WM_SYSKEYUP))
            {
                this.DoTrappedKeyUp(e);
            }

            // Remove any WM_CHAR type messages if supresskeypress is true.
            if (e.SuppressKeyPress)
            {
                this.RemovePendingMessages(WM_CHAR, WM_CHAR);
                this.RemovePendingMessages(WM_SYSCHAR, WM_SYSCHAR);
                this.RemovePendingMessages(WM_IME_CHAR, WM_IME_CHAR);
            }

            if (e.Handled)
            {
                return e.SuppressKeyPress;
            }
        }

        return base.ProcessKeyPreview(ref m);
    }

    private void RemovePendingMessages(int msgMin, int msgMax)
    {
        if (!this.IsDisposed)
        {
            MSG msg = new MSG();
            IntPtr handle = this.Handle;

            while (PeekMessage(ref msg,
                               new HandleRef(this, handle), msgMin, msgMax, 1))
            {
            }
        }
    }

    public void DoTrappedKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do your key down work here
    }

    public void DoTrappedKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do your key up work here
    }
}
```

Please watch out for errors, as I have quickly copied & pasted this togeher from my existing code, which does much more, tailored to my specific use-case. Did not want this here for readability reasons.